# How to savely clone a pytorch module? Is creating a new one faster? #Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, copy, clone

I need to repeatly create some modules, which are completely same.

In the following code, I fill two **same** lists with N **same** modules.

```py
        MIM_N_cell = []
        MIM_S_cell = []
        for i in range(self.num_layers - 1):
            new_MIM_N_cell = MIM_NS_cell(input_dim=self.hidden_dim,
                                         hidden_dim=self.hidden_dim,
                                         kernel_size=self.kernel_size,
                                         model_cfg=model_cfg)
            new_MIM_S_cell = MIM_NS_cell(input_dim=self.hidden_dim,
                                         hidden_dim=self.hidden_dim,
                                         kernel_size=self.kernel_size,
                                         model_cfg=model_cfg)
            MIM_N_cell.append(new_MIM_N_cell)
            MIM_S_cell.append(new_MIM_S_cell)

        self.MIM_N_cell = nn.ModuleList(MIM_N_cell)
        self.MIM_S_cell = nn.ModuleList(MIM_S_cell)
```

Should I use **`.clone()` instead of creating a new module** each time?

I guess cloning may be faster but I am not aware of the side affects of it. If it worth to  clone, how to use it safely (i.e. don't change the *training/testing* behaviour of the network)